# How can I change the color of the active block?

Tags: angular

There is such a list:

```
<div class="media" *ngFor="p of phonebook">
  <a class="list-group-item" (click)="onSelectedPhone(p.id)">
    <h4 class=" media-heading list-group-item-heading"> {{p.name}} </h4>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-9">
        <p class="list-group-item-text">{{p.number}}</p>     
       </div>                  
     </div>      
   </a>
</div>
```

As when clicking on one of the blocks, highlight it with some color showing that this block is now active.

```
  onSelectedPhone(phoneId) {
    this.selectedPhone = this.phonebook.find(el => {
      return el.id === phoneId
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you post your `onSelectedPhone()` function? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Add some runnable snippet to your question so that it will be easy to analyze

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Added an update

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On the `div` tag, add the following:

```
class="{{selectedPhone == p ? 'selectedPhoneClass' : ''}} media"
```

You could also add it onto the `a` tag instead by swapping `media` for `list-group-item`

Comment: I do not quite understand, but how does he allocate it somehow, that is, will it be active?

Comment: assuming the div tag can reference `p` (which it should), it checks the value of `selectedPhone` against `p.id` every time `selectedPhone` changes its value. `selectedPhoneClass` is a css class name, you an change it to any class you want

Answer (score -1):

On the item that you want to be highlighted: `[ngClass]="'list-group-item' + (isSelected ? 'selected' : '')"` Define the boolean isSelected, and a css class to highlight it.

Comment: this would highlight all of the entries, not just 1

Answer (score -1):

You can try with this solution

I Have create a demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-active-block?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
<div class="media" *ngFor="let p of phonebook">
  <a class="list-group-item" (click)="onSelectedPhone(p)">
    <h4 class=" media-heading list-group-item-heading"> {{p.name}} </h4>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-9">
        <p class="list-group-item-text" [ngClass]="{'highlight':p.acive}">{{p.number}}</p>     
       </div>                  
     </div>      
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: that will not de-highlight a number if another gets pressed

Comment: so remove condition on click event

Comment: you can do it without needing to remove it manually, as shown in my example